# using a regex to remove invalid values from image

Tags: mysql, sql

working on a code where we are storing images but some images ending with weird characters

like `, %2C -x1 to x10 etc` or more but always end wih a `.jpg`

how can i regex to replace the image name to be a valid name

here is an example of what i have

```
PCpaste_10_g,-X1,-X2,-X3
SNBar_NEW,-X1
```

they can go till -X10

so i want to have regex to remove `,and everything afterwards it`

i tried using `replace` but that only works for one item at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to find the first occurrence of "," in the field and [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) to grab everything up to the first "," -

```sql
SET @value := 'PCpaste_10_g,-X1,-X2,-X3';
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(@value, LOCATE(',', @value) - 1), '.jpg');
```

or for your update -

```sql
UPDATE <table>
SET image_name = CONCAT(LEFT(image_name, LOCATE(',', image_name) - 1), '.jpg')
WHERE image_name LIKE '%,%';
```

or to handle your `%2C` at the same time -

```sql
UPDATE <table>
SET image_name = CASE
    WHEN image_name LIKE '%,%'
        THEN CONCAT(LEFT(image_name, LOCATE(',', image_name) - 1), '.jpg')
    WHEN image_name LIKE '%\%2C%'
        THEN CONCAT(LEFT(image_name, LOCATE('%2C', image_name) - 1), '.jpg')
    END
WHERE image_name LIKE '%,%'
OR image_name LIKE '%\%2C%';
```

Comment: i forgot to tell, i am using mysql 5.6, locate might not work

Comment: ok, my bad, it works, what if comma is not and there is %2C

Comment: @Jianxee , please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70779159/edit) with all of the possible data variation. If instead of a `comma`, what else can be the delimiter other than `%2C`? and how would all the data look like? will it be consistently the same set of delimiters? Or will it be unpredictable?

Comment: but if there is no , and the imagename column value as `p1022` , it just removes the whole image name and leaves with with just extention

Comment: @Jianxee That is why both my update examples only update offending rows. Why would you try to update a row that doesn't need it?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is consistent with the string before the first `comma` that need to be taken, then you can try with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`;

Let's use this as you sample table & using your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
val VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
('PCpaste_10_g,-X1,-X2,-X3.jpg'),
('SNBar_NEW,-X1.jpg');
```

| val |
| --- |
| PCpaste_10_g,-X1,-X2,-X3.jpg |
| SNBar_NEW,-X1.jpg |

Then first you extract the first string before `comma` occurrence:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,',',1) extracted
FROM mytable
```

returns

| extracted |
| --- |
| PCpaste_10_g |
| SNBar_NEW |

Then to add back `.jpg`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,',',1),'.jpg') extracted_combined
FROM mytable
```

IF your image extension is not consistently `.jpg`, you can do another `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the extension then `CONCAT()` them:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,',',1) ,'.',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,'.',-1)) Extracted_combined
FROM mytable;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63929811ad926b703888d37f5808c44b)

Comment: I don't know why I used LEFT() and LOCATE() instead of SUBSTRING_INDEX(). My mind must have been on other things ;-)

Comment: I can relate to that @nnichols , but I think it's good to have alternatives. ;-)